# How can I install the unity-desktop on Red Hat?

Tags: rhel, unity

I am using a computer system with the gnome desktop system, with which I am not able to work properly (resizing of windows does not work etc). Therefore I would like to install the unity-desktop.

Is that possible on Redhat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.8 (Santiago))? And if so, how?

A simple `yum install unity` did not find anything....

Comment: Not an answer, but may I suggest Cinnamon? It is much better (IMO) than either gnome or unity.

Comment: Sure! So how to install it then?

Comment: `yum install cinnamon` should work. I don't know the package names in the RRH world though. Just search through the repos (same should be true for unity, if you choose to install that).

Comment: I tried that already, but is says: `No package cinnamon available.`

Comment: Try rpm search engines like http://rpmfind.net/. If that still doesn't help, you might need to install from source. Sorry, but I really don't know much about the RH world, haven't used a RH-based system for more than 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

The [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) [Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux] repository is easily added to RedHat and CentOS servers.  It's an excellent, well-vetted source of additional packages not otherwise found in the standard channels.  Install the EPEL package and you should be able to do `yum install cinnamon'.

Comment: I *think* I have installed EPEL by using `yum install epel-release -y`, but still I get the response `No package cinnamon available.` ...

Comment: I don't have a RH 6.8 server available.  Confirm that you in fact have the EPEL repository installed by doing `yum repolist`.

Comment: It says `epel      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64  12,214+1repolist: 59,675` (among other output)

Comment: OK, you do have the EPEL repo.  FWIW, I find `cinnamon` for CentOS-7 at least, that's not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's pretty unstable at this moment, so I can suggest you against it anyway.
Did you tried KDE already?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EkldXVm34w